# Get the children of an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried methods such as:

```
.contents().find("#content")

.get(0).contentWindow.document
```

But neither of them work.
(and yes my iframe src is on the same domain)
EDIT:
The console is logging this:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at contents (jquery.min.js:2:26378)
at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2:3485)
at n.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (jquery.min.js:2:26466)
at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (website.js:4:38)
at HTMLIFrameElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3:6466)
at HTMLIFrameElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3:3241)
```

Comment: Are you calling this inside an iframe load event handler?

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to be ready / load?

Comment: ^ I just realized that...

Comment: Example using `contents().find()` in iframe load callback http://plnkr.co/edit/ESKksyYa2mrJ12Vm9IcQ

Comment: You said it was same domain but your error says different ... *"Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a **cross-origin frame**"*

Comment: ^ Yeah... I haven't transported the files over to my server yet so the files still being on my computer may be causing the issue